# Python - BeautifulSoup Webscrape

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape a list of URLs off of the following website (http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/ftp/cps_ftp.html), but I am having zero luck following the tutorials. Here is one example of the code I have tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url         = "http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/ftp/cps_ftp.html"
page        = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup        = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
cpsLinks    = soup.findAll(text = 
              "http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/basic/")

print(cpsLinks)
```

I am trying to extract these links:

```
http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/basic/201501-/jan15pub.dat.gz
```

There are probably around 200 of those links. How can I get them?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: If it's just those URLs you're trying to find, why not use simple pattern matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to extract the links that *follow a specific pattern*. `BeautifulSoup` allows you to specify [a regular expression pattern](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) as an attribute value.

Let's use the following pattern: `pub/cps/basic/\d+\-/\w+\.dat\.gz$'`. It would match `pub/cps/basic/` followed by one or more digits (`\d+`), followed by a hyphen (`\-`), followed by a slash, one or more alphanumeric characters (`\w+`), followed by `.dat.gz` at the end of the string. Note that `-` and `.` have a special meaning in regular expressions and need to be escaped with a backslash.

The code:

```
import re
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/ftp/cps_ftp.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

links = soup.find_all(href=re.compile(r'pub/cps/basic/\d+\-/\w+\.dat\.gz$'))

for link in links:
    print link.text, link['href']
```

Prints:

```
13,232,040 http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/basic/201501-/jan15pub.dat.gz
13,204,510 http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/basic/201401-/dec14pub.dat.gz
13,394,607 http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/basic/201401-/nov14pub.dat.gz
13,409,743 http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/basic/201401-/oct14pub.dat.gz
13,208,428 http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/basic/201401-/sep14pub.dat.gz
...
10,866,849 http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/basic/199801-/jan99pub.dat.gz
3,172,305 http://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/pub/cps/basic/200701-/disability.dat.gz
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. I tried a regular expression grab as well, but based on your code, I did not have it set-up properly as it grabbed a much larger chunk that was not workable.